# Which Layout is Best for Code base UI in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can you guyz please tell me which layout is best for Creating Code base UI (no layout xml) in android and how i can manager components width and height and its position on different screen resolution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is depending on what design are you gonna implement. give a brief description about your design

Comment: every layout described in xml can be created in java. what is "Creating Code base UI"?

Comment: So layout is completely depends upon your requirement and there are various ways to manage your aspect ratios for different screen resolution you can write the tags in xml.I suggest you to write your requirement in question if you have any.

Comment: Thanks All. @gpasci my requirement is to create some UI of android app using java code. but  i think that ,is difficult to manage that UI on different screen resolution.

Comment: Your requirement is too broad. Is it somekind of class assignment? In any case, narrow your requirement, pick a type of application you want to make, then we'll be able to help you (we can't really help you until then).

Comment: @Abhijit my requirment is to display number of fields with buttons and imageView in table layout. now  i was thinking to which layout i prefer for that?

Comment: Well, there is the layout called TableLayout, but again, without knowing exactly the purpose of your table, it would be difficult for us to tell you if you should pick TableLayout, or RelativeLayout, or something else.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yes its my collage project . in which i have to display student result with there image and a button to open details of that student.

Comment: can you make a wire-frame of your layout and just attach it here.

Comment: Ok then, just use the Layout Designer, generate the right XML layouts, then once you have it working the way you like. Translate the XML into pure Java code and delete the XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None, it really depends on what you want to do.

> how to manage components width and height and its position on different screen resolution.

That one is easy. You'd do it the exact same way you'd manage XML layouts. In any case, you really need to do some basic reading on Android. That question is way too broad.

There are some good youtube videos on Android if you look on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com)

Also, my recommendation is that you do not skip xml layouts until you've learned more about them.